# Getting ServletException and NoClassDefFoundError during webapp startup

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jpa

I'm getting the following errors:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class auth.Login`

and

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence`

How do I ensure my project's configuration is properly setup?

To me, this look correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence` is the root cause of the servlet instantiation error, so we can just ignore the servlet instantiation error for now. A `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the class mentioned in the message was present in the webapp's compile time classpath, but not in the webapp's runtime classpath.

Those JARs which you have there in `/lib` folder should actually go in `/WEB-INF/lib`. This is part of the webapp's runtime classpath. Further you should also **remove** those three `jsp*` and `servlet*` JAR files. They do not belong in the webapp library. They belong in the servletcontainer library. If you did this to fix compile errors, it has to be fixed [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project).

Comment: I found out that EclipseLink library somehow was missing from the Build Path and Deployment Assembly... That was the root of these errors.

Answer (score -1):

I think runtime classpath does not have `servlet-api.jar` and  that is causing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence`

Secondly as said earlier your libraries should be under `WEB-INF/lib` folder to fix the errors